# Make voice call between iOS devices connected to same network

Tags: iphone, networking, call, local

**Is it possible to develop an iOS app that make a phone call using the local network (without internet signal) ...**

*I have 3 stores connected to the same wireless network in my city so I want to do that*

Plz tell me what framework should i use or what's the steps should i follow *if it is possible* ...

Thanks4u in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the closest thing to your question is using Gamekit. Have a look here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/AddingVoiceChat/AddingVoiceChat.html

Comment: This document link is no longer there. I think this is the new link for it http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html